# How to convert NSData to byte array in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays, type-conversion

I want to convert `NSData` to a byte array, so I write the following code:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
int len = [data length];
Byte byteData[len];
byteData = [data bytes];
```

But the last line of code pops up an error saying "incompatible types in assignment".
What is the correct way to convert the data to byte array then?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You can't declare an array using a variable so `Byte byteData[len];` won't work. If you want to copy the data from a pointer, you also need to memcpy (which will go through the data pointed to by the pointer and copy each byte up to a specified length).

Try:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
NSUInteger len = [data length];
Byte *byteData = (Byte*)malloc(len);
memcpy(byteData, [data bytes], len);
```

This code will dynamically allocate the array to the correct size (you must `free(byteData)` when you're done) and copy the bytes into it.

You could also use `getBytes:length:` as indicated by others if you want to use a fixed length array. This avoids malloc/free but is less extensible and more prone to buffer overflow issues so I rarely ever use it.

Comment: Byte byteData = malloc(len); pops up a warning saying "initialization makes interger from pointer without a cast". And byteData turns out to be a byte variable, not a byte array. Any ideas about this?

Comment: There was a small typo in the code, it should work now as matt intended.

Comment: Yes. The second parameter of memcpy should be [data bytes].

Comment: Thanks, iphony, I've fixed the memcpy 2nd parameter.

Comment: Also, in case you didn't spot it yourself... Byte byteData = malloc(len); doesn't work because byteData must be declared as a pointer, i.e. Byte *byteData.

Comment: @matt Gallagher :It works fine,but this conversion make some delay. how  to reduce that... any idea?????

Comment: `Byte byteData[len]` will work with Clang and GCC. This is valid C (C supports variable-length arrays) and therefore valid Objective-C as well.

Comment: My tests show that only the first byte of data will be copied to byteData: byteData[1], byteData[2], etc. contain 0;

Comment: When I used it, it became a Lost Device. What is the reason?

Answer (score 43):

You could also just use the bytes where they are, casting them to the type you need.

```
unsigned char *bytePtr = (unsigned char *)[data bytes];
```

Comment: Doing this, I get a "Variable-sized object may not be initialized" error

Comment: Again, tests show that only the first byte of data will be copied to bytePtr: bytePtr[1], bytePtr[2], etc. contain 0;

Answer (score 16):

Already answered, but to generalize to help other readers:

```
    //Here:   NSData * fileData;
    uint8_t * bytePtr = (uint8_t  * )[fileData bytes];

    // Here, For getting individual bytes from fileData, uint8_t is used.
    // You may choose any other data type per your need, eg. uint16, int32, char, uchar, ... .
    // Make sure, fileData has atleast number of bytes that a single byte chunk would need. eg. for int32, fileData length must be > 4 bytes. Makes sense ?

    // Now, if you want to access whole data (fileData) as an array of uint8_t
    NSInteger totalData = [fileData length] / sizeof(uint8_t);

    for (int i = 0 ; i < totalData; i ++)
    {
        NSLog(@"data byte chunk : %x", bytePtr[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 10):

The signature of `-[NSData bytes]` is `- (const void *)bytes`. You can't assign a pointer to an array on the stack.  If you want to copy the buffer managed by the `NSData` object into the array, use `-[NSData getBytes:]`.  If you want to do it without copying, then don't allocate an array; just declare a pointer variable and let `NSData` manage the memory for you.

Comment: After I add [data getBytes:byteData length:len]; the byteData turns out to be invalid. What might be the problem?

Comment: Try printing the NSData and seeing if it matches; then check the length and make sure it looks like what you're expecting.  If the data is a string, you can also try -[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile].

Comment: I find out the problem: the length shouldn't be a variable. It should be Byte byteData[255];

Comment: Too much Java for me recently. :-) Glad you got it figured out.

Answer (score 2):

That's because the return type for [data bytes] is a void* c-style array, not a Uint8 (which is what Byte is a typedef for).

The error is because you are trying to set an allocated array when the return is a pointer type, what you are looking for is the getBytes:length: call which would look like:

```
[data getBytes:&byteData length:len];
```

Which fills the array you have allocated with data from the NSData object.

Comment: The byteData is invalid. What might be the problem?

Comment: @ChillyZhong try to specify the the byteData size for example `uint8_t *cipherBuffer[16]` then remove the `&` and NSLog(@"%s", (char *)byteData);

Answer (score -1):

Here's what I believe is the Swift equivalent:

```
if let data = NSData(contentsOfFile: filePath) {
   let length = data.length
   let byteData = malloc(length)
   memcmp(byteData, data.bytes, length)
}
```