# How to Pass byte array as parameter in url in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, arrays, url, byte

I am using following code to get bytes array. thx to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724086/how-to-convert-nsdata-to-byte-array-in-iphone/724365#724365).

```
Data *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
NSUInteger len = [data length];
Byte *byteData = (Byte*)malloc(len);
memcpy(byteData, [data bytes], len);
```

it is the right method to do so?

Now, How i can pass bytes array into url?

Thank You for Help,

Answer (score 0):

You're using the right method to extract the raw bytes from the data. To get those into a URL, you'll need to convert them to a string. Exactly *what* string depends on the format that you're submitting (ie. it could be just a list of 1s and 0s, or YES and NO, or any other character(s) as required by the server you're talking to.)

Comment: Hey thank you Ben,
But i have large data to send that's y i am converting into bytes,
any idea how can i do it?

Comment: Without knowing what the server is expecting, there's no way to answer this question.

Comment: Ban, We have ASP.net SOAP based service. server expecting two parameters from iphone or client side. i.e.FileName & FileData (In byte array). Using these we uploading the file on server. Thank You.