# Adding NSData to a NSData Byte Array

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to add an image to a byte array. The following code gives me an error. I think i have not done it correctly.

Error

```
Field has incomplete type 'NSData *__strong[]'
```

In the `.m` file

```
@interface MyViewController() {

    NSData *byteArray[];

}
```

inside the method

```
NSData *imgD = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img1, 0.1);

NSData *imgD2 = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img2, 0.1);        

NSData *imgD3 = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img13, 0.1);

 [byteArray addObject:imgD];

 [byteArray addObject:imgD2];

 [byteArray addObject:imgD3];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create byte array from NSData](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8019382/how-to-create-byte-array-from-nsdata)

Answer (score 1):

```
You can add an image to an array. Use NSMutableArray instead of NSData*[].
```

In the `.m` file

```
@interface MyViewController() {    
    NSMutableArray *byteArray;    
}
```

inside the method

```
byteArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];   
NSData *imgD = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img1, 0.1);    
NSData *imgD2 = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img2, 0.1);            
NSData *imgD3 = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img13, 0.1);

[byteArray addObject:imgD]; 
[byteArray addObject:imgD2];
[byteArray addObject:imgD3];
```

Comment: Please follow Objective-C coding conventions. Instance variables should always start with an underscore, not doing so is the cause of countless errors haunting beginners. And it would be better to make byteArray a property, not an instance variable.