# How to Convert Nsdata to Unsigned or signed Byte array

Tags: ios

in my app i have to upload byte array(Audio ) to server .

BUt now We are getting Nsdata .How to convert this Nsdata to Byte array to post the Audio file to server

Can any one help me?

Comment: Maybe this will help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/724086/how-to-convert-nsdata-to-byte-array-in-iphone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your can use `bytes` method of [NSData](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html);

```
NSUInteger len = [yourData length];
Byte *byteData = (Byte*)malloc(len);
memcpy(byteData, [yourData bytes], len);
```

If your byte is null terminated you can use

```
NSString *content = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:[yourData bytes]];
```

and if not

```
NSString *content = [[NSString alloc]  initWithBytes:[yourData bytes]
          length:[yourData length] encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: how can we print this in nslog

Comment: Can we assign this Byte *bytedata to Nsstring?

Comment: is there any way how we get Unsigned byte array in android like byte rang 0 to 127 .in ios

Comment: any example code for how to upload an recoded audio file to  http server  in ios