# How to convert NSdata to byte array?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to convert NSData to byte array in iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724086/how-to-convert-nsdata-to-byte-array-in-iphone)

I have 20 bytes stored in `NSData`, how can I convert this data to a byte array in objective c?

Comment: hey may be this may help you ..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/724086/how-to-convert-nsdata-to-byte-array-in-iphone