# how to convert byte code into pdf in ios when hit url in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

this is one of my activity I hit a url using NSURL connection and then Parse this data and get JSON data this data in byte code like as
 NSString *ptr= {
    82,
    111,
    111,
    116,
    32,
    50,
    32,
    48,
    32,
    82,
    10,
    47,
    83,
    105,
    122,
    101,
    32,
    51,
    50,
    10,
    47,
    73,
    110,
    102,
    111,
    32,
    49,
    32,
    48,
    32,
    82,
    10,
    62,
    62,
    10,
    115,
    116,
    97,
    114,
    116,
    120,
    114,
    101,
    102,
    10,
    49,
    52,
    51,
    52,
    50,
    55,
    10,
    37,
    37,
    69,
    79,
    70,
    10.........etc
}

I got this in a NSString and after this

```
  NSMutableArray *bytes=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
  [bytes addObject:ptr];

  NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithCapacity:bytes.count];
  NSLog(@"file %@",data);
  for (NSNumber *byteVal in bytes)
  {
    Byte b = (Byte)(byteVal.intValue);
    [data appendBytes:&b length:1];
  }

 NSArray *docDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
 NSString *docDirectory = [docDirectories objectAtIndex:0];
 NSString *fileName = [docDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"abcd.pdf"];
 NSLog(@"file %@",fileName);

 [data writeToFile:fileName atomically:NO];

 NSString *resourceDocPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByDeletingLastPathComponent] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"]];

 NSString *filePath = [resourceDocPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"abcd.pdf"];

 NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
 NSURLRequest *requestFile = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];

 NSLog(@"request path %@",requestFile);
```

This is output. It creates pdf but i can't understand how to open and see the generated pdf file.
 file /Users/rahulsharma/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/CD29ED82-8039-411F-8BBA-2784E5445EDE/Documents/abcd.pdf

```
request path <NSURLRequestfile://localhost/Users/rahulsharma/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/6.1/Applications/CD29ED82-8039-411F-8BBA-2784E5445EDE/Documents/abcd.pdf>
```

Please help me solve this problem on how to get the pdf.

```
 NSString *responseText;
 NSMutableArray *byteArray;
viewdidload
{
  [self report];
 }
-(void)report
{
finished=FALSE;
NSString *case_id=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"8cc61590-42b0-4433-b8ee-25e40d5e6033"];

NSString *investigation_id=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"33a8b03f-4ad2-424a-8aa9-02a07d3937eb"];
NSString *test_id=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"e5a7e867-422c-4365-b920-87fdf5d82783"];


dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];

[dictionary setObject:case_id forKey:@"CaseId"];
[dictionary setObject:investigation_id forKey:@"InvestigationId"];
[dictionary setObject:test_id forKey:@"TestId"];
// [dictionary setObject:Procedure forKey:@"proc"];
// [dictionnary setObject:count  forKey:@"count"];
NSLog(@"dict %@",dictionary);
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionary options:kNilOptions error:&error];
NSLog(@"json %@",jsonData);
NSURL *url1 = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.1.202:81/LaboratoryModule/LISService.asmx/GetpatienttestReport"];
NSLog(@"url is %@",url1);

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url1];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

[request addValue: @"application/json; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

[request setHTTPBody:jsonData];
NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

if( theConnection )
{
    webData = [NSMutableData data] ;
    NSLog(@"%@",webData);

}
else
{
    NSLog(@"theConnection is NULL");
}
while(!finished)
{
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
}
```

}

```
 -(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{

 [webData setLength: 0];
 NSLog(@"web is = %@",webData);
}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
[webData appendData:data];
NSLog(@"web is = %@",webData);

}
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
NSLog(@"ERROR with theConenction");

}
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{

responseText = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:self.webData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSLog(@"val is %@",responseText);

SBJsonParser *par=[[SBJsonParser alloc]init];
NSString *filecontent=[[NSString alloc]initWithString:responseText];
NSDictionary *data=(NSDictionary*)[par objectWithString:filecontent error:nil];
NSLog(@" data is %@",data);
byteArray=[data objectForKey:@"d"];
NSLog(@" string is %@",byteArray);


NSLog(@"DONE. Received Bytes: %d", [webData length]);

finished=TRUE;       
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to open and view PDF file in iPhone then you can use a `UIWebView` to open and show a PDF file.
Pass this `requestFile` in this -

```
[webView loadRequest:requestFile];
```

here `webView` is the variable name for `UIWebView`.

Comment: Actually I don't know that I get pdf aur not I have get path ...when we use load it on webview it show empty ..

Comment: Well in simulator you can use Shift+cmd+g to open that path and can check if file actually exists or not and can use preview app to check file is corrupted or not. if iPhone you can put a check using if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath])

Comment: I have get this message when we open file    It may be damaged or use a file format that Preview doesn’t recognize.

Comment: it's mean that this is corrupted, something is wrong while creating file.

Comment: can you please add what you actually have in NSString *ptr

Comment: I hit a url and after this parse json then get above string something like this and then want to convert this string ptr into pdf

Comment: it's very hard to do this without knowing string value for me. Check out this question which is looking much promising in your case - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15536429/data-corrupt-after-converting-byte-to-nsdata

Comment: I have show whole code please see this and solve my problem i also follow this link but get same error pdf file failed to open\