# How to convert UIImage or NSData to byte Array and post to server?

Tags: ios, post, arrays, nsdata, asiformdatarequest

How to convert `UIImage` or `NSDate` to byte array and post to server.
In my app i have to convert `UIImage` to byte array and  i have to post.

for post  i am using as `ASIFormDataRequest`.

**My code is:**

```
NSUInteger len = [self.dataImage length];
 Byte *byteData= (Byte*)malloc(len);  //converting date to byte array
 [self.dataImage  getBytes:byteData length:len];


 ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlStr]];
  [request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];


 [request addData:self.dataImage withFileName:@"Image.png" andContentType:@"image/png" forKey:@"photo"];
 [request setDelegate:self];
 [request startAsynchronous];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert NSData to byte array in iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/724086/how-to-convert-nsdata-to-byte-array-in-iphone)

Answer (score 1):

Try Like this,

```
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.dataImage ,0.1);
 ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlStr]];
  [request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];


 [request addData:imageData withFileName:@"Image.png" andContentType:@"image/png" forKey:@"photo"];
 [request setDelegate:self];
 [request startAsynchronous];
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by replacing

```
         [request addData:imageData withFileName:@"Image.png" andContentType:@"image/png" forKey:@"photo"];
```

with

```
       [request appendPostData:self.dataImage];
```