# iOS how to convert a .aac audio file to binary data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, binary, nsdata, aac

thanks for your help,my problem is : i need to convert a aac audio file to byte data then i can transmit this data to the server by using tcp.but i can not convert aac to byte. i use:

```
NSString *docDir = NSTemporaryDirectory();
NSString* _tempRecorderPath;
_tempRecorderPath = [docDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ringtones_tmp.aac"];
NSData *testringdata=[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:_tempRecorderPath];
Byte *nbyteData=(Byte*)[ringData bytes];
```

but the result is there is only '\xff' in nbyteData! 
i do not know why ? And how to fix it!!

Answer (score 0):

try this:-

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
NSUInteger len = [data length];
Byte *byteData = (Byte*)malloc(len);
memcpy(byteData, [data bytes], len);
```

This code will dynamically allocate the array to the correct size (you must free(byteData) when you're done) and copy the bytes into it.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724086/how-to-convert-nsdata-to-byte-array-in-iphone) . This link explains exactly what you want

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
NSUInteger len = [data length];
Byte *byteData = (Byte*)malloc(len);
memcpy(byteData, [data bytes], len);
```

Comment: but actually,[data bytes] always equal to \xff, so it can not fix this