# Reading ASCII file byte by byte in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, ascii

I have a ASCII file which I want to read byte by byte into a `Byte` buffer. I am clueless and confused between many aspects. Can anyone guide me with the correct way to do it?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why on earth would you want to read a file byte by byte? What's wrong with using [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL] (or however it's spelled, you look it up yourself).

Comment: why kind of aspects do confuse you so much? because I'm not seeing any in your post...

Comment: I have a file which represents a tree structure (non-readable). So I want the hexadecimal values for each component of the file in a `Byte` buffer. @holex @gnasher729

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finaly got the answer  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724086/how-to-convert-nsdata-to-byte-array-in-iphone). So what I did is,

```
NSMutableString *bundlePath = [NSMutableString stringWithString:
           [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"excercise1" ofType:nil]];

NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:bundlePath];
uint8_t * bytePtr = (uint8_t  * )[myData bytes];
NSInteger totalData = [myData length] / sizeof(uint8_t);

NSLog(@"Data byte chunk: ");
for (int i = 0 ; i < totalData; i ++)
{
    NSLog(@" %x", bytePtr[i]);
}
```

and it worked as I wanted it to be. I got the bytes in an array.