# After updating AudioBufferList Bytes mismatch

Tags: objective-c, nsdata, core-audio, audiobufferlist

********************** Total: **1250 Bytes** ***********************

> Printing description of viewController->dataAudioBytes: f3fed5fe
>   83fe66fd b4fc78fc e1fb5afb 2cfb4dfb b3fb8ffb 32fad5f9 64fbacfc
>   7dfdc3fd 4bfe8cff 1500f2ff edffb400 3c01ef01 56038d04 a704bd04
>   5e054205 c8053206 5505e804 74048a04 9a042504 2f045f03 04027400
>   e7fe63fe effda4fd 1ffd5dfc 81fc64fd 9dfd9efd 81fe51ff 16ffadfe
>   a1fe4bff 57ffdefe 1aff3a00 2301b500 d1ffacff dbfff1ff 5600c500
>   97000200 b9ff3700 8700e400 7501d801 4302e001 4e015b01 a9015901
>   28019101 7d015201 5501c101 5e021f03 9603bb02 67010a01 2c012301
>   5400dbfe 65fed1fe c0ff2b00 d8ffdbff 20002300 47007e00 63006400
>   5c00e800 9d016f01 76008aff 2bff82ff 4dff4bfe f6fc3afc 7efc52fd
>   1efee3fe d2fe69fe 8dfe02fe 8dfd0efe effca7fc b7fd87fd d8fcd4fc
>   6dfd6efe fdfeb8ff 1e0003ff a0fe07ff 5bffb6ff 7eff43ff bdfe56ff
>   e6ff0f00 47009300...

**************** Pick **320 bytes** from **1250 Bytes** *****************

> Printing description of bytes320: f3fed5fe 83fe66fd b4fc78fc e1fb5afb
>   2cfb4dfb b3fb8ffb 32fad5f9 64fbacfc 7dfdc3fd 4bfe8cff 1500f2ff
>   edffb400 3c01ef01 56038d04 a704bd04 5e054205 c8053206 5505e804
>   74048a04 9a042504 2f045f03 04027400 e7fe63fe effda4fd 1ffd5dfc
>   81fc64fd 9dfd9efd 81fe51ff 16ffadfe a1fe4bff 57ffdefe 1aff3a00
>   2301b500 d1ffacff dbfff1ff 5600c500 97000200 b9ff3700 8700e400
>   7501d801 4302e001 4e015b01 a9015901 28019101 7d015201 5501c101
>   5e021f03 9603bb02 67010a01 2c012301 5400dbfe 65fed1fe c0ff2b00
>   d8ffdbff 20002300 47007e00 63006400 5c00e800 9d016f01 76008aff
>   2bff82ff 4dff4bfe f6fc3afc 7efc52fd 1efee3fe d2fe69fe 8dfe02fe
>   8dfd0efe effca7fc b7fd87fd d8fcd4fc 6dfd6efe fdfeb8ff 1e0003ff
>   a0fe07ff 5bffb6ff 7eff43ff bdfe56ff e6ff0f00 47009300

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

       NSData *bytes320 = [[NSData alloc]init];
       bytes320 = [viewController.dataAudioBytes subdataWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 320)];

       ====================== Update AudioBufferList =================

       AudioBufferList *ioData = (AudioBufferList *)malloc(offsetof(AudioBufferList, mBuffers) + sizeof(AudioBuffer *));
       ioData->mNumberBuffers = 1;
       ioData->mBuffers[0].mNumberChannels = (UInt32)1;
       ioData->mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize = (UInt32)[bytes320 length];
       ioData->mBuffers[0].mData = (__bridge void*)bytes320;
}

- (void)encodeAudio:(AudioBufferList *)data timestamp:(const AudioTimeStamp *)timestamp
  {
              NSData *dataBytes = [NSData dataWithBytes:data->mBuffers[0].mData length:data->mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize];
  }
```

**************** Change AudioBufferList Bytes *****************

```
 NSData *dataBytes = [NSData dataWithBytes:data->mBuffers[0].mData
 length:data->mBuffers[0].mDataByteSize];
```

> Printing description of dataBytes: **29a067a8 a1210000 40010000 00000000**
>   f3fed5fe 83fe66fd b4fc78fc e1fb5afb 2cfb4dfb b3fb8ffb 32fad5f9
>   64fbacfc 7dfdc3fd 4bfe8cff 1500f2ff edffb400 3c01ef01 56038d04
>   a704bd04 5e054205 c8053206 5505e804 74048a04 9a042504 2f045f03
>   04027400 e7fe63fe effda4fd 1ffd5dfc 81fc64fd 9dfd9efd 81fe51ff
>   16ffadfe a1fe4bff 57ffdefe 1aff3a00 2301b500 d1ffacff dbfff1ff
>   5600c500 97000200 b9ff3700 8700e400 7501d801 4302e001 4e015b01
>   a9015901 28019101 7d015201 5501c101 5e021f03 9603bb02 67010a01
>   2c012301 5400dbfe 65fed1fe c0ff2b00 d8ffdbff 20002300 47007e00
>   63006400 5c00e800 9d016f01 76008aff 2bff82ff 4dff4bfe f6fc3afc
>   7efc52fd 1efee3fe d2fe69fe 8dfe02fe 8dfd0efe effca7fc b7fd87fd
>   d8fcd4fc 6dfd6efe fdfeb8ff 1e0003ff a0fe07ff 5bffb6ff

Comment: How do you go from `ioData` to `encodeAudio`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Find solution my self.**

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
NSUInteger len = [data length];
Byte *byteData = (Byte*)malloc(len);
memcpy(byteData, [data bytes], len);
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724086/how-to-convert-nsdata-to-byte-array-in-iphone)

Answer (score 1):

You should probably be pointing mData to bytes320's bytes instead of the object itself.

```
ioData->mBuffers[0].mData = bytes320.bytes;
```