# Convert NSData into NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdata

I just need to get what exactly i can see in NSData to NSArray.
the data i am getting

```
<98009900 9a009b00 9c009d00 9e009f00 a000a100>
```

I want it like `[98,00,99,00,9a,00,9b,00,9c,00,9d,00,9e,00,9f,00,a0,00,a1,00]`

I used `[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData: data]`, but this is not giving me as I want.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724086/how-to-convert-nsdata-to-byte-array-in-iphone however hexadecimal `9d` can only be represented by numeric 157 or string "9d".

Comment: What exactly data type does you archive before?