# Flutter how to convert NSData* to Byte* in objc

Tags: objective-c, flutter, flutter-method-channel

I am trying to use c++ api with objc native code in flutter.
https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/platform-channels?tab=type-mappings-obj-c-tab
flutter documentation says `Uint8List` should be stored as `FlutterStandardTypedData typedDataWithBytes:` in objc do

***send argument in flutter***

```
var data = <String, Uint8List>{
      "key": byte,           //data type is Uint8List
      "value": byteBuffer,   //data type is Uint8List
    };
Uint8List? byteRes;
byteRes = await platform.invokeMethod('SeedDecrypt', data);
```

***get argument in objc (AppDelegate.m)***

```
NSData* key = call.arguments[@"key"];
NSData* value = call.arguments[@"value"];

NSUInteger keyLength = [key length];
NSUInteger valueLength = [value length];

Byte* byteKey = (Byte*)malloc(keyLength);
Byte* byteValue = (Byte*)malloc(valueLength);

memcpy(byteKey, [key bytes], keyLength);
memcpy(byteValue, [value bytes], byteLength);

DWORD roundKey[32];

//Call C++ API
//prototype : void SeedKey(DWORD* roundKey, BYTE* byteKey);
SeedKey(roundKey, byteKey);

//protoType : void Decrypt(BYTE* byteValue, DWORD* roundKey);
Decrypt(byteValue, roundKey);

NSData* res = [NSData dataWithBytes: byteValue length: sizeof(byteValue)];

result(res);
```

Store the argument as NSData* and copy the memory to a Byte* variable. After executing the C API, it is converted to NSData type. The problem is that when I run it, the device shuts down. I wrote this source referring to the article below. Do you know what my mistake is?

[How to convert NSData to byte array in iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/724086/how-to-convert-nsdata-to-byte-array-in-iphone)

thanks.

Comment: Do not edit a question to include the answer. The Question field is for questions. To enter an answer, use the Answer field.

Comment: I posted a workaround as a new answer. thanks for the good point

Answer (score 0):

***Solved***

```
NSNumber* keyLength = call.arguments[@"keyLen"];
NSNumber* valueLength = call.arguments[@"valueLen"];

NSUInteger keyLen = [keyLength integerValue];
NSUInteger valueLen = [valueLength integerValue];

FlutterStandardTypedData* key = call.arguments[@"key"];
FlutterStandardTypedData* value = call.arguments[@"value"];

Byte* byteKey = (Byte*)malloc(keyLen);
Byte* byteValye = (Byte*)malloc(valueLen);

memcpy(byteKey, [key.data bytes], keyLen);
memcpy(byteValue, [value.data bytes], valueLen);

DWORD roundKey[32];

//Call C++ API

NSData* res = [NSData dataWithBytes:keyValue length:keyLen];
FlutterStandardTypedData* rest = [FlutterStandardTypedData typedDataWithBytes: res];

free(byteKey);
free(byteValue);

result(rest);
```

See https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/platform-channels?tab=type-mappings-obj-c-tab. After matching the data type, match the OBJC data type with the C data type and return the result.